# How can I use gnuplot-iostream.h to read a data file in C++?

Tags: c++, gnuplot

I have this function:

```
#include "gnuplot-iostream.h"
void DataParser::histogramPlot(const char* filename) {
    Gnuplot gp("tee plot.gp | gnuplot -persist");
    gp << "set boxwidth 0.5\n";
    gp << "set style fill solid\n";
    gp << "plot " << filename << " using 1:3:xtic(2) with boxes\n";
}
```

However when I call

```
 DataParser::histogramPlot("data1.xml")
```

it throws this `error` at line `gp << "plot " << filename << " using 1:3:xtic(2) with boxes\n";`

```
 line 0: undefined variable: data1
 pclose returned error
```

I tried to place "data1.xml" along with the my main project folder and with my executable file. Where does gnuplot run its commands using `gp<<`?

Answer (score 0):

I've made a silly error [=

I have forgot to add quotes `\"`  to the filename gp string stream

```
...
    gp << "plot \"" << filename << "\" using 1:2:xtic(2) with boxes\n";
}
```